# How many bookings I have for each date for each product?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have order and line table.

An order can have one or more lines.
A line references product (bought product), date_at (you can think of a ticket. A date which you can use this ticket)

```
create table o (
 id integer NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE line (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    order_id integer NOT NULL,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    date_at date,
    time_at time,
  );
```

I'm looking for how many `bookings/reservations` I have for each date. 
I can get list of `(date_at, count)` for each date

```
select date(t3.date_at), count(*)
from (
    select t1.id, date(t2.date_at) as date_at, count(*)
    from o t1
        inner join line t2 on t1.id = t2.order_id
    group by t1.id, date(t2.date_at)) t3
group by date(t3.date_at);
```

Now I want the results for each product.

i.e. I want for each product_id, I'd like to get the list of `(date, count)` for orders that contains the product (an order where at least one line contains `product_id`) .

I could run the following query in a loop with different `{product_id}` but I guess there could be a better way

```
select date(t3.date_at), count(*)
from (
    select t1.id, date(t2.date_at) as date_at, count(*)
    from o t1
        inner join line t2 on t1.id = t2.order_id
    where t2.product_id={product_id}
    group by t1.id, date(t2.date_at)) t3
group by date(t3.date_at);
```

I'm using postgres.

---

Test data

```
insert into o(id)
values
(1);

insert into o(id)
values
(2);

insert into o(id)
values
(3);


insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (1, 1, 1, '2017-1-1');
insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (2, 1, 1, '2017-1-1');
insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (7, 1, 1, '2017-1-1');
insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (8, 2, 1, '2017-1-1');
insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (5, 2, 2, '2017-1-1');
insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (6, 1, 2, '2017-1-1');

insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (4, 1, 1, '2017-1-3');
insert into line (id, order_id, product_id, date_at)
    values
    (3, 3, 2, '2017-1-2');
```

I think I just need to group by once more..

```
select date(t3.date_at), t3.product_id, count(*)
from (
    select t1.id, t2.date_at as date_at, t2.product_id as product_id, count(*) as c
    from o t1
        inner join line t2 on t1.id = t2.order_id
    group by t1.id, t2.product_id, date(t2.date_at)) t3
group by t3.product_id, t3.date_at;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want: for each product, for each date, a count of the number of unique/distinct orders which contain at least one instance of that product, then the following should be sufficient.

```
select product_id, date_at, count(distinct order_id)
from line
group by product_id, date_at
order by product_id, date_at;
```

Comment: wow, this seems to work.. I didn't know you could put `distinct` inside count.